# How to add pie chart in the nodes of a dendrogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2, pie-chart, hierarchical-clustering, seurat

I have a dataframe representing a hierarchical clustering of cells (from Seurat). Each cell belongs to a group. I want to plot on the dendrogram a pie chart of the proportions of the different groups for each branch in the tree. I found how to do it if I want pie charts only in the last level of clustering but I need it in branch/node.

I tried to get the coordinates of the nodes in the dendrogram from the following package but didn't succeed: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/clustree/vignettes/clustree.html

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Could you post the code you're working with?